# How would I go about throwing an "optional" exception?

Tags: java, exception

I've got this method I'm working on (I think that's the name) and it essentially tries to match a part of a string and then return the proceeding part of the string - that part I've got, easy stuff. The method is of type String.

When my method fails to find the pattern in the string I want it to return an empty string. I also want to send something along with the empty string to go "hey, I didn't find your key" but I want this to be optional.

This is essentially what I want the method to do:

```
public static String getKey(String key) throws KeyNotFoundException {
    if (key.equals("something")) {
        return "great";
    } else {
        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        return "";
    }
}
```

But the problem with this code is that the `return "";` is obviously unreachable due to `throw new KeyNotFoundException();`.

If I was going to call this method I'd have to use the `try {} catch(KeyNotFoundException knf) {}` block. It's this block that I want to make optional however.

If I choose to be oblivious to the fact the key was not found (e.g. don't use try catch) then I just want to be given the empty string on return.

But I also want to be able to surround it with a try-catch block if I need to know whether the key was found for my operation to complete correctly.

I think I'm going about this the wrong way but I can't seem to figure out an alternative (new to Java), could anyone shred some light on this please?

Comment: In short, what you want is incompatible with what everyone knows and loves under the name "exceptions". What you describe is more like coupling a return value with an error code.

Comment: Alternatively you could have a `getKey(String)` method that returns a blank string as per normal and a `getKeyWithError(String)` which will throw an error when no key is found. It's funky, and I wouldn't suggest it but you can get your "optional" try-catch that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual way to do this would be to write two methods, one which returns a default value, and one which throws an exception. You can have one of these call the other, to avoid duplication:

```
public static String getKey(String key) throws KeyNotFoundException {
    String value = getOptionalKey(key);
    if (value.equals("")) throw new KeyNotFoundException(key);
    return value;
}

public static String getOptionalKey(String key) {
    if (key.equals("something")) {
        return "great";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

The caller can then choose which one to call, based on their needs:

```
String value = getOptionalKey("uma"); // oblivious

try {
    String value = getKey("uma"); // cognisant
}
catch (KeyNotFoundException e) {
    // panic
}
```

Comment: You could also have one command with an optional second parameter. If the second parameter is specified (the default value), it returns it if the key isn't found. If it's not specified and the key isn't found, it throws an exception. I use this strategy for configuration parameter retrieval on occassion.

Comment: @RHSeeger, i see you've been reading my [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7933202/revisions)! The problem with that approach (and why i deleted it) is that if the exception is checked, then the method has to declare it, which means the caller has to write a try-catch block even if they are passing in a default. That would be lame. If the exception is unchecked, then it would be fine, but i'm not a big fan of unchecked exceptions.

Comment: Actually, I didn't even notice you had an edit history, but regardless... This actually isn't a problem. You can actually have two versions of the command, one that takes a default argument (and doesn't throw an exception) and one that doesn't (and does). If I get a chance (busy day today), I'll post an answer that shows the code I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use return values or exceptions to denote an error condition, but not both.

Generally, if you anticipate that something can go wrong, use a return value, and if the error is exceptional, throw an exception (as the name suggests).

Answer (score 1):

By definition, an exception disrupts the normal program flow.  The exception "bubbles up" until someone catches it or the thread terminates.

You can't do exactly what you're trying, but you have a couple options.  You could write a "safe" version of the method that returns a default value if the key isn't found, like you're trying to do, and have a separate method that will throw the exception if the key isn't found.

Another option, if you've defined `KeyNotFoundException` yourself, would be to derive from `RuntimeException` instead of simply `Exception`.  Then, you could remove the `throws` declaration from your method signature and not publish the fact that the method could throw an exception.

You can't, however, throw an exception from the method AND return a value from the method.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could deal with optional return values is to use Java 8's `Optional` class, and let the caller decide what to do when the value is not present:

```
public static Optional<String> getOptionalKey(String key) {
    if (key.equals("something")) {
        return Optional.of("great");
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

You could combine it with the multiple methods approach discussed in other answers:

```
public static String getKey(String key) throws KeyNotFoundException {
    return getOptionalKey(key).orElseThrow(() -> new KeyNotFoundException(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about if you create your own Exception (extend Exception) which will have a constructor that takes a String or whatever you want to send to it (like error code or statement)?

Then you can have a getter method within your Custom Exception that will be used to "get" whatever the error message was.

Comment: Nice idea. But that would only apply for the exception throwing branch. Beginners' questions are always silly :)

Answer (score 0):

nope. a method can only end with returning a value/end or return; if it is void OR throw an exception.

From what I understand of what you want to achieve, you could use a void returning method and provide a reference of a special object in argument. you would then set a field of this object to the result you want to 'return' and throw the exception.

Something like

```
class final ResultHoder {
  String result;
  public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
  }
  public String getResult() {
    return this.result;
  }
}


public static void getKey(String key, ResultHolder result) throws KeyNotFoundException {
    if (key.equals("something")) {
        result.setResult("great");
        return;
    } else {
        result.setResult("");
        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }
}
```